# Ошибка Could not load file or assembly System.Security.Permissions

Tags: c#, mysql

Есть приложение Windows Form, которое делает запрос к серверу mysql, получает ответ и выводит результат запроса в listview, работа с удаленной базой происходит через MySql.Data.MySqlClient. И это приложение прекрасно работает.

Есть второе приложение, оно консольное, и оно должно подключаться к этой же удаленной базе и вписывать в нее данные Insert'ом. Но при попытке это сделать выскакивает ошибка

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Не удается найти указанный файл.

Удаленная база доступна из интернета, так как первое приложение к ней без проблем подключается.

Что самое странное, если из второго приложения вставить кусок кода отвечающий за вставку в базу из второго приложения, то он прекрасно работает, и никаких ошибок нет!

Так же и первое и второе приложение пробовал запускать на одном и том же сервере на windows server 2016, то первое работает (так же с кодом вставки из второго приложения), а второе так  и не работает. В интернете люди ищут ответ на аналогичный вопрос, но решения нигде не описано. Как решить данную проблему?

Код который отказывается работать:

```
try
{   
    MySqlCommand comand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO table(`idsys`, `ip`, `country`, `region`, `city`, `zzz`, `xxx`, `free1`, `free2`, `free3`, `free4`, `free5`, `bufer`)VALUES('004', '1.22.12.79', 'qqq', 'www', 'eee', '12', '2020-07-29 12:12:12', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'buffer')", dbs.getConnection());
    
    
    dbs.openConnection();
    Console.WriteLine("проверка 3");
    if (comand.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
        Console.WriteLine("Вписан в БД");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("НЕ ВПИСАН");


    dbs.closeConnection();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Приложение WinForms под обычный фреймворк? А консольное, небось, под .NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Alexander Petrov! Вы правильно подметили, что консольное под .NET Core. У меня еще слишком мало опыта в c#, и я допустил эту ошибку. Пересоздал консольное приложение из Net Core в NET Framework и все заработало) но я так и не понял вашего замечания про WinForms под обычный фреймворк, что это значит?

Comment: WinForms тоже можно под .NET Core сделать.